# Must chrome be installed in xamarin android when use Azure AD B2C?

Tags: google-chrome, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I am developing android app using xamarin. And I want to use the azure ad b2c to implement my log in funcation. I refer to the sample   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native
.
When I try to finish the sample, I find it worked fine in uwp and iOS, but not android. In android, it always try to open the url with chrome, if there is no chrome in the android device, the app is crashed. 

So can I change the browser instead of the chrome in default? Because I can't ask my end users to install the chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this is very important for developers. Usually, MSAL in Android or iOS requires support for Custom Chrome Tabs for displaying authentication prompts.

So, if you don't want to use the Chrome , you need to use different library, not MSAL. Such as [**AppAuth for Android**](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android). But using different library will need you change the way of authorization.

I also suggest you can post this idea in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=160596), the Azure AD Team will see it. I will also report this feedback to Azure PG.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,@GaryZhu. If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer, so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Currently, Xamarin Android in MSAL can only launch chrome or chrome custom tabs. If the device doesn't have them, it will cause an exception.

Embedded webview support in MSAL will be an option in the near future.
Here's a link to the issue in the [MSAL repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/547).